# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG

Tags: php, google-chrome, dropzone.js

I am using **dropzone js** to upload bulk users.
The file format is **CSV.**
When I am trying to upload less number of users, everything is fine.
But when number of users(records) increases, for example, **1000**, it shows error in console :  `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG`

**Note:** In any case users get uploaded successfully, only issue of getting response. (uploading means: inserting records in database).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also got ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG error in Chrome.

The reason was that PHP sent Set-Cookie header with each session start in my case. And when long ajax request was finishing, server sent all Set-Cookie headers to the browser.

To fix this I removed the Set-Cookie headers by calling 
`header_remove('Set-Cookie');` before the output or before setting flashdata in codeigniter.